# Which, in order are the physically strongest & quickest; Vulcan, Klingon, Romulan, Jem'Hadar, Borg drone, Cardassian, Bajoran, & Trill?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, star-trek-ds9, star-trek-tos, star-trek-eu

I used the major protagonists and antagonists in the Alpha and Beta Quadrants. If you'd like to add some Delta Quadrant like the Vidiians or the Kazon, you're more than welcome. If you have other species in the Alpha and Beta Quadrants that are bipedal similar type species you'd like to add, feel free. Please make sure to add humans in there as well as a base.

I am speaking of an average member of each species. I know males and females can vary. Also the strongest Human might be stronger then the weakest Jem'hadar, or whatever. I'm just looking for an average.

When speaking of strength I am referring to physical strength. I am not referring to mental abilities or anything of that nature. I only want to know physically which species can lift more weight for example using their muscles. I realize some species might have more or less, upper or lower body strength. I'm just looking for overall average strength.  It doesn't literally have to be a squat, curl, bench press, or anything that specific..

For example:

> Vulcans were on average three times physically stronger than Humans,
>   and had considerably faster reflexes. (DS9: "Take Me Out to the
>   Holosuite")

I know there's an episode where Kirk is worried about Spock and states how much stronger spock is but I can't seem to find it.

As for speed, I am looking generally at reflexes. So maybe quickness helps frame what I mean by speed.

I'm looking for a definitive list if one exists. The reason I am curious is that I often see hand to hand combat in the STU that doesn't make sense to me.

I don't own any Star Trek reference manuals or anything like that and I couldn't find anything online.

If someone can string all or even some of these species together from various episodes or reference manuals it'd be most helpful.

If there's something that's published even if it's not STU that'd be great.  Anything done by STU writers in a non-canon format would also be acceptable. If it's something EU that's published that'd be ok too. I just don't want a link to somebody's opinion that isn't authoritative in any way, like a here's my favorite list type of site.

Comment: I am doubtful any such authoritative resource exists because the only people it would matter to would be fans. In scripts, the person who wins is the person who NEEDS to win to move the story along. Judging from watching the series:

Vulcan, Romulan, Jem'Hadar, Klingon, Borg Drone, Cardassian, Human, Bajoran, Trill

Vulcan and Romulans share genomes. Jem'Hadar tended to defeat Klingons in fights, Borg Drones tend to be stronger than Humans but could be beaten by Klingons, Cardassians and Humans seem evenly matched. Bajoran and Trills don't seem much stronger than Humans and are less violent.

Comment: @Thaddeus my understanding is that there are many resources that are canon that were put out there for fans. But I'm not sure about that. In any event if such a list doesn't exist or can't be put together, than I guess my curiosity won't be quenched. As for Klingons, I just watched an episode where Worf tore through about ten Jem'Hadar by himself. But I guess Worf isn't typical as he can also tear through ten Klingon's by himself.

Comment: The Jem'Hadar bragged about how they were defeating the Klingons regularly until Worf showed up. He was the exception not the rule.

Comment: From my brief bit of research I can give you a little bit on the physical strength aspect, but I'm not sure about quickness sorry :(

Comment: Trill is an impossible one to answer. The symbiont is as weak as a worm, the host is x strong.

Comment: I'm sorely tempted to post the top trumps cards.

Answer (score 6):

Based on the Memory Alpha pages and my personal recollection, I can provide *some* information, but it seems unlikely that we're going to get a huge amount of information to support this.  I've drawn up this list for physical strength for you from what I reason is strongest to least strong:

1. Borg Drone
2. Jem'Hadar
3. Klingon
4. Romulan
5. Vulcan
6. Human

Now, this doesn't address all your species I know, but this is the best I could come up with and it is speculative at times.  Here's my reasoning:

- The Jem'Hadar are generally able to defeat a Klingon (kudos to @Thaddeus), so they're stronger than a Klingon
- Worf was beaten by a Borg Drone (TNG:*Q Who*), but he could defeat a Jem'Hadar, so the Borg are probably the strongest species
- Klingons are fairly fierce and have a far greater emphasis on physical training than do Romulans who tend to be more sneaky (just a general observation I've made, not based on any sources sorry), so Klingons are probably stronger than Romulans
- Considering Romulans have a greater emphasis on aggression than the Vulcans, it seems logical that the Romulans would be stronger (again, speculation)
- Vulcans have time and again proven their greater strength than humans (as pointed out in the question and on Memory Alpha), so humans get the bottom ranking

Comment: Wouldn't Romulans and Vulcans be the same since they're genetically so similar(identical right?). You really put Klingons above Vulcans? Vulcans are stronger than humans because of the gravity on their planet, I believe this is stated in TOS. Hopefully others will add with other episodes as well. I look forward to it. +1

Comment: @JMFB the genetic similarities is why I put Vulcans and Romulans so close to one another, but based on their different cultures I reasoned there might be differences.  Again, I put Klingons over Vulcans because of cultures.  If you find any evidence to counter it please feel free to modify this post!

Comment: @JMFB just letting you know that b/c this is a community wiki, reputation doesn't get affected by votes and editing is easier to do ;)

Comment: but if Romulus doesn't have the same gravity or greater gravity than Romulans would be weaker I would think.

Comment: @JMFB that is entirely possible, but do we know what the grativy is like on Romulus relative to Vulcan (or Earth for that matter)?  Besides, considering these are space-faring races there would probably be differences across those living on different planets too

Comment: @JMFB Romulans and Vulcans aren't identical, [and this has been a plot point](http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/The_Enemy_%28episode%29). Romulans are either parallel branch of the genus (like a more distant Vulcan Neanderthal) or heavily genetically modified.